# how to check if a passed arguement is a mixin

Tags: pug

I have a mixin that takes another mixin (callback if you will)
how to check if the passed argument is a mixin so that it doesn't break my code??

I tried

```
p #{mixins}  //- nothing gets outputed
p #{Object.keys(pug_mixins).length}  //- 0
p #{JSON.stringify(pug_mixins)}   // {}
p #{globals}  //- nothing gets outputed
// but in vain
```

and the funny thing is when I mistype the mixin on purpose when calling it
the error that gets logged starts with `pug_mixins.templatee is not a function` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

edit: I also tried browsing the source code && the doc but nothing helped

edit2: it seems like it only works when wrapped in a function! why's that???

### doesn't work

```
mixin myMixin()
    em smth

#container
    if pug_mixins['myMixin']
        h2 200
    else
        h2 404
//- 404
//- WHY????
```

### Works

```
mixin myMixin
    h2 200:)!

-
    const typeCheck = val => {
        if (pug_mixins[val]) {
            return 'mixin'
        } else {
            return 'text'
        }
    }

mixin myMixin2(val)
    #container
        case typeCheck(val)
            when 'mixin'
                +#{val}()
            when 'text'
                p 404:')
            default
                p i hate my life

+myMixin2('myMixin')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
mixin bar(m)
  | before_
  if pug_mixins[m]
    +#{m}
  | _after

mixin foo
  b foo

+bar("foo")
= " "
+bar("baz")
```

gives this output: `before_<b>foo</b>_after before__after`

Note that `pug_mixins` is sensitive to the order of your code.

Edited to add:

You must also actually call the mixin at some point for the mixin name to be in `pug_mixins`.  Note that in your not-working example, you check for the mixin's presence, but don't actually call it.

Comment: thanks but looks it only works when wrapped in js function
could you help me plz?
i updated the question

Comment: Note that this does the same thing as your code with the function:

```
mixin myMixin
  h2 200:)!

mixin myMixin2(val)
  #container
    if pug_mixins[val]
      +#{val}()

+myMixin2('myMixin')
```

It looks like if you never actually call the mixin, pug will not include it in pug_mixins.

Comment: Okay, this works, but I haven't called the mixin in the working example, have I?
edit: sorry I can't upvote your answer as I need 4 reps more

Comment: In the working example, you *do* call the mixin, with `+#{val}()`

Comment: but I'm calling the typeCheck befor calling the mixin, then how?

Comment: My theory is that there's some sort of tree-shaking going on, so if the mixin is never called, it gets eliminated from the compiled template.

Comment: that makes sense.. actually that's the only logical explanation for this weird behaviour XD
anyway thanks a lot really
appreciate your help:)